# Unused default export - React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I am trying to export my main component in the `App.js` file, but 'export default' in the line

> "export default class App extends Component"

comes up unused. This is the only export default statement in the project. When I try running the project it crashes. I've posted the source code to my app.js below

More info: I'm using WebStorm to build this app and it's telling me the 'export default' statement is unused. When I run the app I get no errors but it crashes as soon as it is opened.

Can someone tell me what is wrong here or how to fix this issue?

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import {LogCell} from './LogCell.js';
import {Header} from 'react-native-elements';

export default class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Header
                    placement="left"
                    leftComponent={{ icon: 'date-range', color: 'white', size: 30}}
                    centerComponent={{ text: 'Feb 2', style: { color: 'white', fontSize: 20} }}
                    rightComponent={{ icon: 'edit', color: 'white', size: 30}}
                    backgroundColor={"rgb(0, 100, 250)"}
                />
                <ScrollView style={{width: '100%', paddingLeft: '5%', paddingRight: '5%', paddingBottom: '5%'}}>
                    <LogCell></LogCell>
                    <LogCell></LogCell>
                    <LogCell></LogCell>
                </ScrollView>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        alignItems: 'center',
        // justifyContent: 'center',,
    },
});
```

Comment: What is the error that you're seeing when it crashes?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways.

**one**

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
export default class App extends Component {
```

**two**

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
class App extends Component {
...

export default App
```

Comment: @jimmyruby You probably didn't get it right. Look at my revised code.

Comment: @jimmyruby I copied and pasted your code and tested it, but there was no error. Do you want to exit and try running again?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207256/discussion-between-jimmyruby-and-hong-developer).

Comment: @jimmyruby  If you are using expo, try using this statement. `expo start -c`

Answer (score 0):

You have to import like :

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
```

and then `export default class App extends Component`

hope it helps. feel free for doubts

Comment: where have you imported it?

Comment: In the source code above I import it in the first line

Comment: no i mean, where have you imported App, must be in some other page

Comment: As far as I know App doesn't have to be imported if it is the default class being exported. This is in the App.js file